PowerShell pipeline input ByPropertyName
Given a text file modules.txt with these contents:
Microsoft.Powershell.Archive
Microsoft.Powershell.Management
Microsoft.Powershell.Utility

I want to get the commands defined in each module.
This works:
Get-Command -Module (Get-Content .\modules.txt)

But this does not, despite Module being defined as accepting pipeline input by variable name:
get-content .\modules.txt |select @{n='Module';e={$_}} | Get-Command

This error is returned:
Get-Command: The term '@{Module=Microsoft.Powershell.Archive}' is not recognized as a 
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.

My question: why does the second approach fail, if the Module parameter is defined as accepting pipeline input ByPropertyName.? And is there any way to make the pipeline approach work? (Example from chapter 10 of PowerShell in a Month of Lunches).
Update
To determine whether the issue was the string vs. string[] mismatch, I tried the following:
[string[]]$a = @("Microsoft.Powershell.Archive")
$b = [PsCustomObject]@{Module=$a}
$b | Get-Command

This received:
Get-Module: The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: @{Module=System.String[]}

But I had more success with directly creating a CSV:
"Module","Verb"
"Microsoft.Powershell.Archive","Get"
"Microsoft.Powershell.Utility","Get"
"Microsoft.Powershell.Management","Get"

Now
import-csv .\modules.csv | Get-Command

produced the expected results.

how about using pscustomobject?

@Mr.Key7, my expression is returning that:
gc .\modules.txt | Select @{Name='Module';Expression={$_}} | %{$_.GetType()}

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object


ByParameterBinding appears to be limited to the case where there are more than one parameters being bound.
This works:
gc .\modules.txt |
Select @{Name='Module';Expression={$_}}, @{Name='Verb';Exp={'*'}} |
Get-Command

But this fails:
gc .\modules.txt |
Select @{Name='Module';Expression={$_}} |
Get-Command

Since the parenthesis syntax is available, this is not a functional limitation, and this shows that ByParameterName is usable, as long as it is part of a set of parameters being passed.
Note: the same behavior occurs with Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.4, so this appears to be a stable limitation of ByParameterName.
